# Can I use expansions with the second edition without owning the first edition?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

I'm looking to pick of Mansions of Madness now that the second edition has been released. I know that the first edition had a several expansions released, and I know that the MoM [second edition website](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/mansions-madness-second-edition-showcase/) says that owners of the first edition *Forbidden Alchemy* and *Call of the Wild* expansions are able to use pieces to expand the second edition. But the wording is unclear whether or not owners of *only* those expansions can make use of pieces from them to expand, or if the first edition is also required.

Is there any benefit to buying the second edition and those expansions? Is there anything from the expansions that I'd miss out on without the first edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you don't have the first edition core game, you will still be able to use "Call of the Wild" and "Forbidden Alchemy" to expand your second edition.

(However, the "Suppressed Memories" expansion for second edition will probably be a better choice in financial terms.
It contains all the components from "Call of the Wild" and "Forbidden Alchemy" that are used by second edition)

Comment: Oh, wow. I hadn't even seen them announce that. That seems perfect!